# Does disable_recursion_pending protect from invalidating recursive_directory_iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, filesystems, invalidation, boost-filesystem

I want to delete a folder while recursively traversing through the filesystem. Here's my code:

```cpp
using namespace std::filesystem;

for (recursive_directory_iterator it(path); it != end(it); ++it)
{       
  auto entry = *it;
  if (entry.is_directory() && entry.path().filename() == "test")
  {
     it.disable_recursion_pending();
     remove_all(entry);
     continue;
  }
}
```

It works. But will it fully protect me from invalidation? And why?